# Csproj target doesn't copy exe in output

Tags: c#, msbuild

If I remove `$(OutDir)*.exe` everything copies correctly (dlls, json, etc), exe file stays in output directory (obviously I want it to be copied too) in Distribution folder.
If I add it - nothing copied and error risen.

How to copy referenced exe file?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyProj\MyProj.Tool.csproj">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToMoveToDistribution Include="$(OutDir)*.dll;$(OutDir)*.pdb;$(OutDir)*.json;$(OutDir)*.exe;" />
   </ItemGroup>      

   <Target Name="Fill distribution folder" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="Moving binary files @(FilesToMoveToDistribution)"/>
        <Move SourceFiles="@(FilesToMoveToDistribution)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)Distribution">
          <Output
            TaskParameter="DestinationFiles"
            ItemName="FilesWritten"/>
        </Move>
        <Error Text="Failed to move binary files" Condition="'@(FilesWritten)' == ''" />
      </Target>
```

Comment: It is possible that the file is locked by a process or there're insufficient permissions to write to the destination folder.

Comment: Im under administrator, and this project doesn't run a thing. It just accumulates everything in single build. It seems that exe generated after Build, and not present at the moment.

Comment: Are you running antivirus or behind a firewall? can you see an error in msbuild logs or windows events?

Comment: nothing, just my error

Comment: @eocron Your target is performing a `Move`, not a `Copy`. Try copying the file and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the issue: I would recommend avoiding using spaces in target names. i.e. change "Fill distribution folder" to "FillDistributionFolder".

Comment: Not working. Im trying to move, because referenced assembly is needed as binaries in subdir. I don't need copies all over output result. Selecting subdir on reference doesn't work either - it will copy only dll itself without deps/exe.

Comment: Try to collect binary logs (`msbuild -bl`) and inspect such a logs with the `MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer` (https://msbuildlog.com/). This will show you what files are selected and what operation are performed on each file.